# QT version seems to be older than installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtmultimedia, kde-plasma

I'm new to QT and QML, I found a cool KDE Plasma addon on the internet and wanted to edit it, but [flushMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#flushMode-prop) property, which I want to use, was introduced in QT 5.13. I have installed QT 5.15 (to be exact, 5.15.3), rebooted and got `file:///filename.qml:58:2: "VideoOutput.flushMode" is not available in QtMultimedia 5.8.` I also checked that qt5-multimedia is `5.15.3+kde+r0-1` (latest from arch linux repository), checked the QT version in system settings, everything says it's 5.15, but in the logs it acts like it's 5.8. Is it possible that I have 2 different qt5 installations, or why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you very likely have two Qt installed. You got system Qt package that comes with desktop environment, I believe it does not include development files (headers), to obtain them you installed `qt-something-dev` package that installed another Qt as dependency.